# What's the relationship between sound speed and acoustic phonons?

Tags: acoustics, phonons

In the textbook, it says that the slope of the acoustic branch of phonons equals to the sound speed. There are 3 kinds of acoustic phonons including TA and LA phonons. Does it mean that there are also 3 sound speeds in the crystal?

Comment: Longitudinal and Transverse wave do travel at different speeds, typically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are as many branches of acoustic phonons as there are dimensions of the crystal, but they are not necessarily distinct. These three branches will each have a "speed of sound" associated with it, given by the gradient of the frequency-wavenumber graph at the origin. If these are different, it means that the speed of sound will be different in different directions.

Answer (score 0):

Often the "speed of sound" is defined as the slope of the acoustic branch *as the wavevector goes to zero* (the "acoustic limit" -- where phonons behave like waves in a continuum material). So yes, there can be multiple speeds of sound. Two TA branches can converge as the wavenumber goes to zero, in which case they'd have the same "speed of sound".

By the way, there can be multiple speeds of light in (birefringent) crystals too, so this phenomenon is not unique to phonons.